# Зачем нужна операция new с размещением?

Tags: c++

```
char j[999];
int* p1 =new (j) int;
int* p2 =(int*) j;
```

Чем отличается инициализация `p1` от `p2`? Если отличий нет, то зачем тогда нужна операция `new` с размещением?

Comment: Прошу прощения, а откуда у вас берется вообще термин "размещение"? просто общепринятым является "разыменование"

Comment: @S.H. placement new размещает создаваемый объект в указанном буфере.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Placement-new вызывает конструктор для объекта, передавая в качестве `this` указанный адрес. Иными словами, он создает объект по указанному адресу.

Но placement-new также можно использовать для типов без конструкторов (т.е. не классов), и для классов с *тривиальными* (не делающими ничего) конструкторами. Причина для этого неочевидная:

Кроме собственно вызова конструктора, у placement-new есть второе, более туманное назначение. Он **создает** объект, начинает его lifetime (жизнь).

Жив объект или нет нельзя определить глядя на содержимоме памяти, это введенная в стандарте абстракция. Placement-new для типа без конструктора (если не указать инициализатор), или для класса (если вызывается тривиальный конструктор) компилируется в 0 процессорных инструкций, его эффект чисто формальный.

Попытка получить доступ к неживому объекту вызывает неопределенное поведение, просто потому что в стандарте так написано. Хотя, на практике, если ваш тип - не класс, или класс с тривиальным конструктором по умолчанию, часто все будет работать как надо.

Placement-new возвращает указатель на свежесозданный объект. В вашем примере, `p1` указывает на свежесозданный `int`, а `p2` **не** указывает, хотя численные значения указателей одинаковые.

Почему "не указывает"? Потому что в стандарте так написано. Попытка что-то прочитать или записать в `*p2` вызовет неопределенное поведение. Однако, `*std::launder(p2)` будет работать.

Зачем нужно такое неопределенное поведение? Вероятно, чтобы разрешить компилятору выполнять более жесткие оптимизации, связанные со strict aliasing.

Comment: Очень крутой ответ!

Comment: Разве можно передавать в placement new указатель на элемент массива `char`? Массив `char` не является типом, который может _предоставлять хранилище_ (_provides storage_) для размещения объектов... В отличие от массивов `unsigned char` и `std::byte`...

Comment: @wololo, по крайней мере g++ возражений не имеет

Comment: @wololo Да? Ссылку на стандарт бы... Подходит любой тип, ЕМНИП.

Comment: @avp Так-то он в примере из вопроса он и вообще без placement-new вряд ли стал бы возражать. :)

Comment: Вообще-то я задал вопрос в надежде получить ссылку на стандарт от вас, что "Подходит любой тип" или что-то вроде того. :) Ну, ладно... Смотрите: [intro.object/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#3).

Comment: @wololo Хм! Интересно, что список типов не совпадает с http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#13 , где `char` есть. Мне кажется, что понятие "provides storage" вводится только с целью дать опеределения другим понятиям ниже; там не написано что для других типов будет UB. Нормальный пруф пока не нашел, но нашел http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#3 где в качестве указателя в placement-new передают тот же тип, объект которого им создают, хотя он тоже не provides storage.

Comment: По поводу второй ссылки не очень понял. Если вы имеет ввиду `new (au.data)`, то там `data`  — это массив `unsigned char`.

Comment: @wololo Пардон, не ту ссылку скопировал. Вот эта: http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#example-2

Comment: @wololo, а если без казуистики, можете  объяснить, чем одна память существенно отлична от другой?

Comment: Это пример "особого случая" — _transparently replaceable_. Разрушить объект типа `T`, а потом создать на том же самом месте другой объект, того же типа можно. Даже указатели и ссылки ссылавшиеся на старые объект остаются валидными и теперь ссылаются на новый объект. (Что само по себе уже не обычно для стандарта.)

Comment: @wololo Это означает, что "provides storage" не является необходимым условием осутствия UB. :Р

Comment: @avp Да вся часть стандарта про lifetime - сплошная казустика. Вот чем p1 отличается от p2, если у них значения одинаковые? Самое интересное, что указатели вообще trivially copyable. Если я разберу p1 по байтам и соберу в другом месте, он все еще будет показывать на тот новый int? А p2? D:

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, тогда зачем вообще читать такие стандарты? (imho они уже давно оторвались от реальности)

Comment: @avp ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ [Чтиво в тему.](https://habr.com/en/post/497114/)

Comment: Надеюсь когда-нибудь стандарт починят. С++20 и так много сделал в эту сторону (использование malloc без placement-new в духе С уже не UB, к примеру).

Comment: Судя по всему, вы правы, и можно смело размещать объекты поверх других объектов. Но всё таки как-то странно. Пусть есть код `int* p = new int; short* p2 = new (p) short;`. Мы переиспользуем память, на которую указывал `p`, следовательно, время жизни объекта типа `int` подошло к концу, следовательно, указатель `p` теперь невалидный. Как освободить память?

Comment: @avp, `можете объяснить, чем одна память существенно отлична от другой?` Это вы у авторов стандарта языка спросите. Я придерживаюсь позиции, что если есть возможность, то неопределённого/определяемого реализацией поведения нужно избегать по максимуму. Так мне спится крепче. Но такое количество UB в стандарте я не считаю нормальным. Когда написание программы превращается в "а не попадает ли этот код под одно из сотен UB размазанных тонким слоем по 1500-страничному талмуду", то становится как-то грустно: а тем ли я вообще занимаюсь?..

Answer (score 1):

При new c размещением объект создается, а при касте - нет. Во втором случае разыменование указателя будет являться неопределенным поведением. А в первом - нет, указатель `p1` указывает на только что созданный объект `int`. Для объекта типа `int` разница выходит чисто формальная, а вот для любого объекта с нетривиальным конструктором, например `std::string`, без размещения с `new` будет гарантированное фиаско.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! + не поставил т.к не могу завершить регистрацию(

Answer (score 0):

Оператор `new Type` выделяет память **и** вызывает конструктор объекта типа `Type`.

Оператор `new` с размещением только вызывает конструктор в указанном месте памяти.

Его используют если свободная память уже есть, а нужно только про инициализировать объект.

```
class Type{
..
} ;
..
// выделяем память для 10-и объектов типа Type
Type * p = malloc(sizeof(Type)*10);
// вызываем конструктор 5-го элемента
new(&p[5])Type();
// вызываем его деструктор 
p[5] . ~ Type();
// освобождает память от десяти объектов
free(p);
```

---

Команда `delete` - аналогично вызывает деструктор объекта **и** освобождает память.

Прямой вызов деструктора делает **только** свою работу.

---

Ещё один пример для прямого вызова конструктора получается используя объединения **union**. Так как все элементы объединения автоматически **не** инициализируются, то их нужно вызывать вручную.

```
// g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c++11 lazyc.cpp -o lazyc
# include <new>
# include <iostream>
class C{
public:  
  C(){std::cout<<"C()"<<std::endl;}
  ~C(){std::cout<<"~C()"<<std::endl;}
};

class LazyC{
public:
  
  LazyC(){}
  
  void newC(){
    if(live){
      c . ~ C ( ) ;
      new ( & c ) C ( ) ; }
    else{
      new ( & c ) C ( ) ;
      live = true ; }}
      
  void delC(){
    if (live){
      c . ~ C ( ) ;
      live = false ; }}
      
  ~LazyC(){
    if (live)
      c . ~ C ( ) ; }
      
private :
    
  union{
    C c;
  };
  
  bool live { false };
  
};

int main(){
  LazyC l;
  std::cout<<"main:sleep"<<std::endl;
  l.newC();
  std::cout<<"main:exist"<<std::endl;
  l.delC();
  std::cout<<"main:closed"<<std::endl;
}
```

проверка

```
> ./lazyc
main:sleep
C()
main:exist
~C()
main:closed
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! + не поставил т.к не могу завершить регистрацию(